# Adding Same Column Header Names to all worksheets in an Excel Book

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a script that will create worksheets based on the number of files that it finds in a directory. From there it changes the name of the sheets to the file name. During that process, I am attempting to add two Column header values of "**Hostname**" and "**IP Address**" to every sheet. I can achieve this by activating each sheet individually but this becomes rather cumbersome as the amount of sheets goes past 20+ and thus I am trying to find a dynamic way of doing this regardless the amount of sheets that are present.

This is the code that I have to do everything up to the column header portion:

```
$WorksheetCount = (Get-ChildItem $Path\Info*.txt).count
$TabNames = Get-ChildItem $Path\Info*.txt
$NewTabNames = Foreach ($file IN $TabNames.Name){$file.Substring(0,$file.Length-4)}
$Break = 0

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

$null = $Excel.Worksheets.Add($MissingType, $Excel.Worksheets.Item($Excel.Worksheets.Count), 
$WorksheetCount - $Excel.Worksheets.Count, $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1).Type)
1..$WorksheetCount
Start-Sleep -s 1

ForEach ($Name In $NewTabNames){
        $Break++
        $Excel.Worksheets.Item($Break).Name = $Name
}
```

I have attempted to insert my code as such:

```
ForEach ($Name In $NewTabNames){
        $Break++
        $Excel.Worksheets.Item($Break).Name = $Name

        $cells=$Name.Cells
        $cells.item(1,1)="Hostname"
        $cells.item(1,2)="IP Address"
}
```

When I attempt to run the script, I get the following error..

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

And then it proceeds to list each line of the code that I had put in. I thought that since I created a variable during the operation, that it was the issue:

```
$cells=$Name.Cells
```

I thought That perhaps if I moved it before the ForEach command that it would resolve it but I still receive the same issue. I have looked through various ways of trying to select ranges of sheets within excel via powershell but have not found anything helpful.

Would appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: `$cells=$Name.Cells` is the issue, but not due to you creating a variable, `$Name` is just a string, it doesn't have a `.Cells` property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried multiple things there... $name, $NewTabNames, anything that could possibly get me what I wanted. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Its been years since I worked with excel but pretty sure you need to loop through $Excel.worksheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually my first post in StackOverflow ever and I feel pretty excited to finally help out. I made some small modifications to your code and seems to work fine. I noticed some odd behavior when I removed the $null variable that was getting assigned because it seemed strange to me why it was being done, but after removing that assignment my outlook application open by itself automatically every time I ran the script. I found the site where you got the code from just to see if there were any changes to the original code.

I found [this Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839805.aspx) very helpful to figure this out.

[This is what I modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB0It.png)

```
ForEach ($Name In $NewTabNames){
    $Break++
    $Excel.Worksheets($Break).Name = $Name

    $Excel.Worksheets($Break).Cells(1,1).Font.Bold = $true
    $Excel.Worksheets($Break).Cells(1,1) = "Hostname"
    $Excel.Worksheets($Break).Cells(1,2).Font.Bold = $true
    $Excel.Worksheets($Break).Cells(1,2) = "IP Address"
```

}

Comment: Worked just as I hoped! Thank you! Also I'm a bit dumbfounded that it was that easy! Thanks again for the documentation!